# Laravel Collection Macro Filter by Today

Tags: laravel, eloquent, collections, laravel-collection

I have the following scenario:

1. A businesses table whose model has transactions as:

```php
    public function transactions(): HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
    }
```

2. A transactions table (transactions belong to a business) - has an id, amount and timestamp columns.

I am displaying all the businesses in a blade view with their transactions count and value. Now I want to filter the transaction count and value by today's date. I have seen the best way is to do a Collection Macro. Here is what I have so far in App Service Provider (which is not working):

```
Collection::macro('filterByToday', function ($value) {
     return $this->filter(function ($value) {
         return $value->created_at === Carbon::today(); 
     });
});
```

How can I write this macro such that in blade I can loop through all the businesses displaying this transactions like:

```
@foreach($businesses as $business)
   Count: {{ $business->transaction->filterByToday()->count() }}
   Value: {{ $business->transaction->filterByToday()->sum('amount') }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Please clarify what is not working. BTW, the relationship name is `transactions` but you are using `transaction` in your blade template

Comment: what @porloscerrosΨ said maybe the issue. But you also have to make sure to declare the macro to the boot method to AppServiceProvider

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ the filter is not working. And yes, thats a typo. It should be transactions

Comment: @Beri the Macro is already defined in the AppServiceProvide boot method. The filter is not working though. I suspect my logic is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your macro should not receive any arguments and be defined in the `boot` method of a `ServiceProvider` class.

If you're using a custom `ServiceProvider` class, make sure it is registered in the `$providers` array in `config/app.php`

```php
# AppServiceProvider
public function boot()
{
    Collection::macro('filterByToday', function () { // <-- 0 arguments
        return $this->filter(function ($value) {
            return $value->created_at === Carbon::today(); 
        });
    });
}
```